# How do I specify string references in perl-mode and not make Emacs dizzy?

Tags: emacs

I need to use references to (constant) strings in Perl.  If I write:

```
my $a = \'test';
print $$a;
```

Emacs (23.3.1)'s perl-mode thinks that a string starts at the *second* apostrophe and messes up filling and fontification.  Using double quotes (`"`) doesn't change this.

How can I work around this without using extra variables or switching to cperl-mode which I find rather "loud"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a space after the backslash. Perl does not care and perl-mode catches up.